# Интересное поведение апача

Tags: apache

Добрый день. Есть сервер на убунту десктопе (т.е. с кучей дефолтных настроек).
Я добавил вот такой сайт

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName sitename.pp.ua
ServerAlias sitename.pp.ua
ServerAdmin mail@sitename.pp.ua    
DocumentRoot /home/alexey/www/sitename.pp.ua/www/
<Directory /home/alexey/www/sitename.pp.ua/www/>
Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /home/alexey/www/sitename.pp.ua/logs/error.log
AccessLog /home/alexey/www/sitename.pp.ua/logs/access.log combined

LogLevel warn

ServerSignature On

</VirtualHost>
```

Но с этими настройками при наборе sitename.pp.ua я вижу индекс /var/www, а не /home/alexey/www/sitename.pp.ua/www/

Но если я в конце имени сайта добавлю точку (т.е sitename.pp.ua**.**), то попадаю куда надо в /home/alexey/www/sitename.pp.ua/www/ Я читал, что точка это как бы и есть домен самого-самого нулевого уровня, но браузеры мол сами дописывают ее в конце.

Вобщем куда нужно ткнуться, что бы исправить это?

Comment: наверное в настройки самого апача. конфиг его нужно смотреть

Comment: 1. Вам здесь ServerAlias пока не нужен.
2. Покажите, что в логе \access.log
3. Какая директория по-умолчанию с каким именем? (для этого читайте предыдущего оратора)